# Merging Text Nodes Together After Inserting Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension where I am storing/retrieving a section of the DOM structure (always a selection of text on the screen) the user has selected. When I am storing a selection, I enclose the section in a SPAN tag, and highlight the text in yellow. This causes the DOM structure around the selected text to split up into various text nodes. This causes a problem for me as when I try to restore this selection (without refreshing the page) it causes problems as the DOM structure has been modified.

My question is how do I prevent the DOM structure from splitting up after inserting the SPAN? If this cannot be achieved, how would I reassemble the DOM structure after removing the SPAN tag to its original state?

```
//Insert the span
var sel = restoreSelection(mootsOnPage[i].startXPath);
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
var newNode = document.createElement('span');
newNode.className = 'highlightYellow';
range.surroundContents(newNode); 


//Original DOM structure
<p>Hello there, how are you today</p>


//What the DOM looks like after insertion of SPAN
<p>
  "Hello there, "
  <span class="highlightYellow">how</span
  " are you today"
</p>
```

Comment: Why does this matter?  Do you have other code that depends on a specific structure?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am using code found here ( http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html ) to help me store/restore a selection of text. It requires that the DOM structure is unchanged.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification and good luck

Comment: Thank you :) I've been digging around for a bit but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You can use this to unwrap your content.

```
$(".highlightYellow").contents().unwrap();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R4hfa/

Comment: As I read the OP's question, they are not asking how to remove the span.  They are asking how to reassemble the text nodes that were split when the span was added.

Comment: from what I understood, he is highlighting the part of a content and stores it and when he tries to restore it back then he gets the modified content because of highlighting (which added extra spans).

This `My question is how do I prevent the DOM structure from splitting up after inserting the SPAN?` can not be done unless he wraps the entire text by `span.highlightYellow`. Instead my reply answers this `how would I reassemble the DOM structure after removing the SPAN tag to its original state?` question.

Comment: Your question answers how to remove the span tag that was inserted.  If that's all he was asking then, you've got it.  I thought they were asking how to put the text nodes back to the way they were before they were split around the span tag which I attempted to answer.  The one thing we might agree on is that the question isn't entirely clear on this point.

Answer (score 108):

Use [element.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize).

After you remove the span you inserted, you can use the [element.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize) method to merge the extra text nodes that were created as a result of the insertion/removal of the span. The normalize() method puts the specified element and all of its subtree into a "normalized" form (i.e. no text nodes in the subtree are empty and there are no adjacent text nodes). Found, thanks to @tcovo's comment.

Text nodes inside of an element are broken apart if you insert nodes and then remove them. Unfortunately they don't automatically re-merge once the extra node is removed. To answer peoples' questions as to "why" this matters, it usually causes issues when working with text highlighting in your UI.

Comment: Holy crap, thanks! I've been looking for 2 hours. Keep in mind, `normalize()` needs to be called on a DOM element and not a jQuery object. You'll need to select the first object in the jQuery selector array like `$('section.scope p')[0].normalize();`

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work on ranges inside contentEditable :(.

Comment: 10 years later and still useful. Thank you,

Comment: How to prevent creating new text nodes after press "Enter" and use only one text node in contenteditable element? Prevent AUTO-SPLIT initial text node in contenteditable element

Answer (score 6):

The very act of inserting a `<span>` tag will alter the DOM.  That's, somewhat by definition, what you're doing when you call `surroundContents()`.  You can't add a span tag without altering the DOM which includes splitting text nodes and adding new elements for the span.

Further, unless the selected text includes only whole text nodes and the selection never starts/stops in the middle of a text node, you will have to split text nodes to put the span in the right place.  When you later remove the span tags, you will have extra text nodes.  That shouldn't really matter to anything, but if you really think you have to get the split text nodes back to the way they were, I can think of a couple options:

1) Save the original parentNode before the span is inserted into it.  Clone it, add your span to the clone, replace the original node with the clone and save the original.  When you want to restore, put the original back and remove the cloned one.

2) When you remove the span, run a function that looks for neighboring text nodes and combine them.

3) Figure out why it matters that there are more text nodes afterwards than there were before because this should not matter to any code or display.

Comment: I know this is old, but your #3. It can matter for text highlighting plugins that rely on text nodes. If the plugin is looking at all text nodes of the selected elements for matches, it won't find a match that is split between two adjacent text nodes (possibly due to a previous highlighting that was undone). Merging the two would solve that problem, although i guess the highlighting plugin could do that while it is looking for matches.

Comment: I just want to add a comment regarding #2. There is a DOM method which does this: [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.normalize)

Comment: @tcovo - Interesting.  I never knew about normalize().  Good to know.

Comment: #3 it matters a lot when calculating ranges. If text nodes have been added any saved ranges will break. So yes it definitely does matter to some code.

Answer (score 2):

When using `normalize()` pay attention!
It will strip away nodes like `<br/>` and will alter the text and its visualisation.

`normalize()` is good, but it has its drawbacks.

So `<p>"this is an "<br/>"example"</p>` will turn into `<p>this is an example</p>`

Is there a way to use `normalize()` but keeping the `<br/>`s?

Comment: that is not true, `normalize()` does NOT remove `<br/>` tags. Take a look on this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9b0mo4s/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate and then remove the second node

```
node1.textContent += node2.textContent;
node2.remove();
```