# How to remove all <wbr> tags on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, wbr

I'm trying to make a chrome extension for youtube comments, but when I add some stuff it keeps adding

```
<wbr></wbr>
```

tags, is there any way to remove all of those tags on the page in javascript?

Comment: Well you might start with [`.getElementsByTagName("wbr")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
var wbrs = document.getElementsByTagName('wbr');

while (wbrs.length) {
    wbrs[0].parentNode.removeChild(wbrs[0]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Awsfn/).

Comment: That demo doesn't work for me (in Chrome) for some reason - the same code will work to remove `div` elements, but not `wbr` ones...

Comment: My apologies, it does work. What didn't work was when I had `<wbr>Test</wbr>`, but of course the `<wbr>` tag isn't supposed to contain content, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn: yeah, *I* made that mistake in my first run...this question marks the first time I've had to do an element-check (to see what the element actually *is*) in good couple of years. =)

Comment: Why thank you kindly! And, for the record, I'm *so* glad it wasn't just me... =)

Comment: After removing the `<wbr>` tags you maybe need to combine all text nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19217435/318765