# How to format HTML content or selection "correctly"?

Tags: javascript, html

I am playing with container `<div>`, which property contentEditable is set to "true". I was very happy to format selection of text this way:

1. Select text with mouse
2. Retrieve HTML of the selection
3. making new string: e.g. `<font color = "red">` + HTML selection + `</font>`
4. Replace selected HTML with the string above

It seemed perfectly OK, but when applied this method several times, i recieved HTML text like that:

```
The oldest browsers <font color="Red">support only </font><font color="Red"><font color="Red">one<font color="Red"> way</font></font><font color="Red"> of</font> registering event handlers</font>, the way invented by Netscape.
```

and that is is really ugly. I would like to get nice formated piece like:

```
The oldest browsers <font color="Red">support only one way of registering event handlers</font>, the way invented by Netscape.
```

I tried apply selection.normalize(); before adding starting and ending tags, but it did not help.

What is the correct method changing HTML, in order to get "normal" result"?

thanks

Code sample:

```
<script>
    function FontRed() {
        embraceSelectionWithTag('<font color=Red>', '</font>');
        }


    function embraceSelectionWithTag(tag1,tag2) {
        var range, html;
        html = tag1 + getSelectionHtml() + tag2;
        range = replaceSelectionWithHtml(html);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }


    function getSelectionHtml() {
        var html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                container.normalize();
                html = container.innerHTML;
                return html;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                //container.normalize();
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
                return html;
            }   
        }
    }



    function replaceSelectionWithHtml(html) {
        var range, html;
        if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;
            while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
                frag.appendChild(child);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);
            return range;
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.pasteHTML(html);
            return range;
        }
    }
</script>    

<body>
    <div id="containter2" contentEditable = true>
    The oldest browsers support only one way of registering event handlers, the way invented by Netscape. 
    </div>

    <button onclick="FontRed()">Font Red</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are working with

Comment: FYI   `<font>` tag is deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl: I know, this is just an example...

Comment: @statosdotcom: this is not what I am asking. I wonder, if there are functions in webkit or some "correct" way of HTML element input, which would automatically check and repair HTML syntax.

Comment: May be related to `element.normalize()`, your text is being split into multiple nodes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849316/merging-text-nodes-together-after-inserting-span

Comment: @user2867288: that I wanted to do so, but this did not help

Comment: So, this is to be expected based on your design. You're only modifying the HTML of the current selection. In order to merge all of your deprecated font tags, you'll need to operate on a larger section of the dom that contains all of the selected elements.