# can adjacent text nodes in the DOM be merged with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Suppose I have a sentence in the webpage DOM that when I examine it, consists of 3 text nodes followed by perhaps some element like BOLD or ITALIC.  I want to merge the text nodes into one text node, since having adjacent text nodes is meaningless - there is no reason to have them.  Is there a way to merge them easily?
Thanks

Comment: Can I see some code about this?

Comment: If you don't want to destroy the actual DOM, then you need to search for all of them and combine them manually into the first of them and removing the other ones. Otherwise you could try by replacing [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) by itself, which in most cases would result one text Node again. But what is the reason why you care about that?

Comment: *"There is no reason to have them"*: there seems no reason either to not have them. Leave this to the browser to manage.

Comment: I have a range application that depends on some stability in the DOM.  So if every time the user selects some text a new text-node is created, pretty soon I have swiss cheese.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Text Nodes Together After Inserting Span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849316/merging-text-nodes-together-after-inserting-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```js
var parentNode = document.getElementById('pelements');
var textNode = document.createElement('p');

while (parentNode.firstChild) {
  textNode.textContent += parentNode.firstChild.textContent;
  parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.firstChild);
}

parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
```

```html
<div id="pelements">
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `Node.normalize()` is doing exactly what you want.
You can refer to: [Node.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize)

Comment: See jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/ymzjp7u6/27 for a working example of this. (You would need to use Inspect to see the nodes, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to specify the parent element. It should be possible to traverse the whole DOM and every node, but if you can avoid that, it would be better.

```
nodes = document.body.childNodes;
nodesToDelete = [];

function combineTextNodes(node, prevText) {
    if (node.nextSibling && node.nextSibling.nodeType == 3) {
        nodesToDelete.push(node.nextSibling);
        return combineTextNodes(node.nextSibling, prevText + node.nodeValue);
    } else {
        return prevText + node.nodeValue;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        nodes[i].nodeValue = combineTextNodes(nodes[i], '');
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < nodesToDelete.length; i++) {
    console.log(nodesToDelete[i]);
    nodesToDelete[i].remove();
}
```